# Upgrading from Java Config to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Upgrading an existing system to Spring Boot with Auto config.  Currently the system is all Java config.  I'm confused over whether to continue the use of `@Profile`.  Is this annotation no longer needed?  I searched extensively about upgrading and found only references to non-Spring Java migration and creating new projects.

Typical `@Profile` usage in our configuration classes looks something like:

```
@Bean
@Profile("is-standalone")
public Service unsecuredService(SomeApi someApi) {
    return new ...
}
```

I inferred from the Spring Boot examples that using one of the `@Conditional` annotations is recommended like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("unsecured.enabled")
public Service unsecuredService(SomeApi someApi) {
    return new ...
}
```

Then in a `YAML` file the `is-standalone` Profile enables or disables all the various properties for that Profile.  Is this the proper way to upgrade?  To repeat a question from above differently, can the `@Profile` usage be left as is?  This is for a fairly large project, the upgrade is non-trivial, so I would like to do this only once!

Answer (score 0):

Depends where your previous `@Profile` annotation is coming from. If you're using Spring's [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html), the functionality is as follows:

- Annotating a class with `@Profile("dev")` will load the class and register it in the Spring context only when the `dev` profile is active
- Annotating a class with `@Profile("!dev")` will load the class and register it in the Spring context only when the `dev` profile is inactive

If this sounds like what you have already, no change is needed.